# Let $E$ be an inductive ordered set, then $\forall a\in E$ ($\exists$ a maximal element $m\in E$ $\ni$ $a\leq m$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read the following in a book:
**Theorem**: Let $E$ be an inductive ordered set and let $a$ be and element of $E$. Then there exists a maximal element $m$ of $E$ such that $m\geq a$.

If I understand correctly, an inductive ordered set does not necessarily have to be totally ordered. So $a$ can be an element that's not comparable to any other element of $E$. Then there exists no $m$ such that $m\geq a$. Shouldn't we add a condition: $a$ is comparable to some element in $E$?

Comment: $a$ is always comparable to $a$

Comment: @Max That's it! Thanks.

Comment: The positive integers N, are inductively ordered and though 1 in N, there is no maximal number > 1.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Interesting! Apparently this theorem only works for finite sets.